# Rails validates_presence_of not working with HTML form text area

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, validation, forms, model

Environment: Rails 2.3.11 w/ MySQL 5.0

Here is my slideshow model:

```
class Slideshow < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :description
end
```

Using the console, if I run:

```
Slideshow.new(:title => "", :description => "").save!
```

it returns:

```
Validation failed: Title can't be blank, Description can't be blank
```

which is correct.

However, when I submit a blank HTML form to the create action:

```
def create
  @slideshow = Slideshow.new(params[:slideshow])
  if @slideshow.save
    redirect_to(...)
  else
    render(:action => 'new')
  end
end
```

only the `:title` field fails validation. I've verified that what is being passed in the params is:

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Submit", "slideshow"=>{"title"=>"", "description"=>""}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"manage/slideshows"}
```

Why is the description field NOT failing validation here?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you displaying your validation errors??

Comment: After the form post, I'm using `f.error_messages`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
validates_length_of :description
```

for more details ... http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_length_of

Answer (score 0):

when You submit a blank HTML form to the create action, it should go in else of create action and your form should have this line:

<%= f.error_messages %>

to show you the errors.

Comment: I'm using `f.error_messages` there. After posting a blank form, the only error message that appears is "Title can't be blank".

Comment: means validation is working for other fields. can you show where you have put the validation.. or share you project folder with me.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a syntax issue. It was occurring on a testing server where there were two models with very similar names (one an updated version of the other). During testing I used the wrong one. My apologies for any unnecessary head-scratching :)